# Omega subtheme - Dropdown menus not working properly

Tags: theming

When on http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=corporateclean the source for About menu item is:

```
<li class="expanded"><a title="About" href="/corporateclean/node/3">About</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a title="Our Team" href="/corporateclean/node/3">Our Team</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a title="Our Vision" href="/corporateclean/node/3">Our Vision</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

However, on my site, when on the homepage, the source for Privacy (a menu item which has pages hanging off it) is as follows:

```
<li class="collapsed"><a href="/content/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
```

It's only when I am ON the Privacy page, that the dropdown menus appear when I hover over the Privacy menu item. The source now is:

```
<li class="expanded active-trail"><a class="active-trail active" href="/content/privacy">Privacy</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/content/advice-0">Advice</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/content/complaint-management">Complaint management</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

What am I doing wrong, and why aren't the dropdown menus being displayed when on the homepage for example, but instead only when I am ON that page?

Answer (score 1):

The usual behavior is for sub-menus to only expand when you are on the parent item; so if you have a tree like the one below, you would only see a dropdown containing "Child" when you are on "Parent":

- Home

  - Parent

    - Child
    - Child
    - Child

**SOLUTION:**

1. Go into the menu list links  which is admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu for the main menu and edit the item you want expanded ("Parent" in this case)
2. Check the checkbox "Show as expanded"

That item will now be expanded no matter where you are on the site.